# Export a view as text file having fixed column width

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

it looks like nothing has been developed in Drupal 7 to export views content as fixed column width flat file.

How can I enable a user to export a view with such format?

Thanks!

Comment: any guess anyone? I am probably going for a database direct extract using SQL code. If you have any better idea please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can export Views data into various file formats using **[Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)**. Module provide supports for exporting data in

- CSV
- Microsoft XLS (or really simple HTML understood by Excel)
- Microsoft DOC
- Basic TXT
- XML